# How can one correctly use a relative pronoun in this case?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

This is my sentence example:

*A* gives access to the decomposition of *B*, **which** is given by *C*.

What I want to convey is that *B* is given by *C*. And not *A*, nor *B* and nor *decomposition*. How do I achieve that? By using **which**, **that** or even no relative pronoun?

Comment: So what is it that C gives to B?  Access, value, or what?

Comment: You do it in exactly the way you have. Because of the comma, *which* can only refer to B. Without the comma, it is at best ambiguous and *which* probably would refer to *decomposition.*

Comment: It's the opposite way round, Andrew. Because of the comma "which" can have the NP "the decomposition of B" as antecedent. Without the comma, "which" would refer to "B". The comma is, as it happens, correct here, so we need to know what it is that C is providing to B.

Comment: @BillJ C gives more details about how B is defined. It really just gives another more specific, formal name. That's why I separated both B and C.

Comment: @Belzebu Do you actually use the <A>, <B> and <C> in your sentence or are they replaced by other technical terms?

Comment: @BillJ Andrew, erm, you've both got that squiffy there folks. Whether the relative clause is  supplementary (non-restrictive, non-defining etc) or integrated (restrictive, defining etc) has no bearing on which NP it relates to. In either case it could be *the decomposition of B* or just *B*.

Comment: @Araucaria The point is that in integrated relatives, the antecedent is a noun, normally the nearest one. In supplementary relatives, the antecedent can be a noun phrase (or clause etc.). I realise that overrides are possible, of course.

Comment: @BillJ Well, I get where you're coming from, but that won't work here, I don't think. The reason is that the description of the grammar is simplified somewhat. In an integrated relative clause the antecedent is usually a *nominal*, not an NP. Of course a nominal is not always a noun. Here, if the relative clause is integrated, there is a choice between the nominals *decomposition of B* and *B*. If it is supplementary, then we have a choice between the NPs *the decomposition of B* and *B*. So the distinction between integrated and supplementary will not disambiguate ...

Comment: @BillJ ... whether the (ultimate) Head of the antecedent phrase is *decomposition* or *B*. Hmm, don't know of I've been very clear there?

Comment: @Belzebu So what about: "A gives access to the decomposition of B, whose definition is given by C".

Comment: @Araucaria I didn't say an NP - I said a noun, though it can be a nominal. Where _of_ phrases occur in integrated relatives, it is perfectly normal to take the oblique as antecedent.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I agree (I understood your NP/noun distinction in the original). My point was just that there's two nominals there ... :)  (good solution, btw)

Comment: @Araucaria Indeed, they are replaced by technical terms. Ongoing research..

Comment: @BillJ It somehow doesn't fit in mind mind. But I'm going to think if I can come up with something in these lines. Thanks a bunch, you guys

Comment: @BillJ By using *whose definition*, it certainly corresponds to * B*, right?

Comment: That would I think be the plausible interpretation, but where there is an _of_ phrase, as in your example, there is always the possibility of ambiguity. Generally, though, in such cases it is normally assumed that the nearest noun (i.e. the noun that follows "of") is the antecedent.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence as it stands is always going to be ambiguous & cause some confusion as to whether you are referring to "B" or to "the decomposition of B" as "given by C".

You could circumvent any possible confusion by restructuring & restating that it is B you are referring to:

> A gives access to the decomposition of B, in which B is given by C.